# VirtualBox (VT-x/AMD-V enabled) Ubuntu main machine crashes

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

i have several virtual machines running on virtual box on my main Ubuntu OS.

But after the security updates (Spectre and Meltdown) on windows they weirdly stopped working.
I tried looking up the problem on google but it seems like no one else has experienced this problem.

Side Notes:

- I have 2 OS-Systems (Windows/Ubuntu) running on a dual boot.
- I have VT-X/AMD-v enabled in my BIOS settings and i disabled Hyper-V
  on my Windows machine
- I dont know how those two OS-Systems are even connect but i noticed
  that my time switches about a hour if i first start Ubuntu and then
  Windows. Therefore i guess that they are linked in some way
- Some of the Virtual Machines require VT-X/AMD-v. I tried starting
  those who dont require VT-X/AMD-v without it and they worked fine.
- All machines worked perfectly fine before

Not sure if this question is off-topic on this website.  If it is i'd be happy if someone can link me to places where this question is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is most likely a bug in the Virtualbox. Submit an issue to their bug tracker.

> I have VT-X/AMD-v enabled in my BIOS settings and i disabled Hyper-V on my Windows machine

This is fine and is actually required.

> my time switches about a hour if i first start Ubuntu and then Windows.

Most likely the timezone settings are different in two OSes, or one OS assumes that the CMOS clock runs in UTC and another thinks it is in local time zone. It has nothing to do with your problem.

> Some of the Virtual Machines require VT-X/AMD-v.

Apparently pure application level software works fine, but hardware-accelerated VMMs require kernel modules to be loaded, and those may need adjustments after kernel updates, especially so drastic ones.

> Not sure if this question is off-topic on this website.

Yes, it looks like this question is more suitable for ServerFault https://serverfault.com/